# math.floor is supposed to return integer

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get the integer part of a number after dividing two variables.
ie, get 3 if the value is 3.75
displaycount and itemcount are both integer variables.

```
    Dim cntr As Integer        
    cntr = Math.Floor(Math.Abs(itemCount / displaycount))
```

That code produces a blue squiggly in VS2012 with the comment that "runtime errors may occur when converting Double to Integer" BUT Math.Floor is supposed to take a decimal or double and return an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Math.Floor is supposed to take a decimal or double and return an integer." No, it isn't. It returns a value of the same type as its argument. See the documentation, e.g. [Math.Floor Method (Double)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb.aspx).

I would have expected VS to suggest a fix of adding CInt() around the RHS of the assignment; did that not appear for you?

Comment: Math.Floor Method
.NET Framework 4.5 Other Versions 
Returns the largest integer less than or equal to the specified number......That is directly from MSDN, anyway CInt wrapped around it does work, TY

Comment: @Dinotom It's the use of the word 'Integer' that's confusing here - the value returned is an integer in the sense of a 'whole number' but the datatype is still double or decimal as determined by the call parameter. In fact if you look at the 'syntax' section in the link you provided, you'll see this.

Comment: @peterG I agree that the documentation is lacking in explicitness.

Answer (score 2):

If you need an Integer as  result, consider using either the `CInt`, `Int` or the `Fix` functions.

- **CInt** rounds to the nearest integer using the bankers's rounding (n.5 rounds towards the closest even number).
- **Int** removes the fractional parts. Negative numbers are truncated towards smaller numbers
  `Int(-8.4) = -9`.
- **Fix** removes the fractional parts. Negative numbers are truncated towards greater numbers
  `Fix(-8.4) = -8`.

See [Conversion.Int Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1497ek4.aspx) and [Type Conversion Functions (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx).