# Groovy: Math.floor return non-integer (0.0), need to cast to int always?

Tags: groovy

I discovered `Math.floor` returns not integer (returned 0.0 in my code) (in JSR223 in JMeter). Is it Groovy proper and universal functioning? I was not able to find docs on `Math.floor` on https://groovy-lang.org as it is as I see it external library, not integral part of the language - am I right?, but on [tutorialspoint on Grrovy](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_floor.htm):

> Return Value − This method Returns the largest integer that is less
>   than or equal to the argument. Returned as a double.

For some other systems on SO there are answers for this which tell return type is same as argument, e.g. [math.floor is supposed to return integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347298/math-floor-is-supposed-to-return-integer). I'd like confirmation for Groovy.

Comment: the answer and my mistake are so simple maybe question is worth deleting?

Answer (score 0):

I was not very attentive at reading tutorial, it says (I even posted it here): `Returned as a double.`.